# regex matches line break-why?

Tags: regex, notepad++

in notepad++ this pattern `([\t\s\,])+` which I intended to match a tab a space or a comma matches line breaks (`\r\n` in notepad). Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\s` represents any white space character. It will match tabs, but it will also match new lines and carriage returns because those too are white space characters.

If you want to just match tabs, spaces, or commas, use a pattern like this:

```
[\t ,]+
```

Comment: Does the comma need to be escaped? It's used within the `{1,}` structure, right?

Comment: @thomas No, you don't. Most special characters don't need to be escaped within a character set. In general, you only need to escape a character if there is some possibility of confusing it with a special character. e.g. if you wanted to match any `[` or `]` character you would need to escape `]` in `[[\]]` but not in `[][]` because the engine expects at least one character in the set so the first `]` is interpreted literally.

Answer (score 2):

`\s` matches all whitespace characters.

Space matches space.

Answer (score 1):

> **Why is this?**

Because `\s` will match whitespace characters also.